# Toggle between 2 VisualForce pages in same window - development mode opens multiple times

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton

I have 2 Visualforce pages which represent 2 different views of the same data - one a list view and the other a detail view. I have toggle command buttons on both and would like them both to open in the same window, which I have managed to do now, but am seeing the Development Mode sections stacking up at the bottom of the screen, which is obviously not ok. How can I stop this happening?

The top screenshot is the detail VF page with a button to the listview page.
The bottom 3 are all of the Listview page, where every time it is opened (after toggle back to the detail view and then back to the listview), an additional Development Mode section is displayed!

[image]

If I open the ListView in a new window, this doesn't happen. 
The code for my 2 buttons is below:

```
<apex:commandButton id="CCActivitiesListView" action="{!GetActivities}" title="Call Cycle Activities ListView" value="Call Cycle Activities ListView" 
                                onclick="location.href=('/apex/CallCycleListView?id={!CallCycle.Id}');return false;" />

<apex:commandButton id="CCActivitiesView" action="{!view}" title="Call Cycle Activities View" value="Call Cycle Activities Detail View" 
                                onclick="location.href=('/apex/CallCycleView?id={!CallCycle.Id}')" />
```

I have 2 remoting calls in my controller, which I've made global, as well as having made the controller global, in order to avoid the javascript remoting error I was getting on clicking the ListView button to have this view open in the same window.

I don't know what is causing the Development Mode to do this, and would like to know how to stop this - help please?

Comment: Obvious answer - turn off development mode. There are so many bugs and memory leaks with that depending on the browser it is not really all that useful IMHO and you will find that you can do without it once you turn it off.

Comment: Thanks Eric - I have turned it off, but I was wondering what was happening in the background that I might need to be concerned about. If it's related to bugs in the DevelopmentMode code that's ok, I can live without it :).

Comment: Lets see what other comments come up but that was my experience 3 years ago (double dev mode bars) and looks like it is still an issue.....Since my comment is only a workaround and not a direct answer, lets see what else the guru's have to say